# combine google documents into one

Tags: doc

I have 6 documents each with the format below

Header

Text

table 1

Bullet Points

table 2

Text

I want to combine them into one doc - however when I tried this code it dose not work.Please if anyone can advise please

`

```
function mergeDocs() {
  var docIDs = ['list-of','documents','ids','you should have somehow'];
  var baseDoc = DocumentApp.openById(docIDs[0]);
  var body = baseDoc.getActiveSection();

  for( var i = 1; i < docIDs.length; ++i ) {
    var otherBody = DocumentApp.openById(docIDs[i]).getActiveSection();
    var totalElements = otherBody.getNumChildren();
    for( var j = 0; j < totalElements; ++j ) {
      var element = otherBody.getChild(j).copy();
      var type = element.getType();
      if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH )
        body.appendParagraph(element);
      else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE )
        body.appendTable(element);
      else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM )
        body.appendListItem(element);
      else
        throw new Error("According to the doc this type couldn't appear in the body: "+type);
    }
  }
`
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question from `I want to combine them into one doc - however when I tried this code it dose not work.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: Hello, no worries. The goal is to combine 6 documents togheter. The structure of the template is above. I tried to use the code as above but it didn’t work. Please if you can advise. Thank you!